# How to setup a wireless connection with an Eee PC 1005?

Tags: 10.04, wireless, ubuntu-netbook

How to setup wireless in ubuntu 10.04 netbook edition in EEpc 1005? Do I need to install some drivers and how?
PS I am running ubuntu dual boot with XP (in XP have wireless Internet)

Comment: How did you install ubuntu? wubi?

Answer (score 2):

I have a 1005HA, and wireless worked out of the box. I did have to specifically enable wireless in the BIOS for it to work though, for some reason it came disabled!

Answer (score 1):

according to this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks), wireless and various other pieces of hardware should work out of the box. If you install with wubi this might have causes some issues from my experience that is usually the cause.

I hope the link is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the wireless for that model needs to use Windows wireless drivers using ndiswrapper.
[This forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1390856) discusses this issue for a similar model.

Also see [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper).

Comment: That was karmic (9.04), the wireless is supposed to work out-of-the-box in lucid. I have a couple of 1005 at work, I'll try to boot to one of them to see what happens.